# Remove bottom area

Tags: slds

I am calling child aura component inside another aura component. But it seems somehow there is a extra bottom area coming up. How can I remove this?

```
<lightning:card>
 <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
  <lightning:layoutItem size="12" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="12" largeDeviceSize="12" padding="around-small">
  //something here
  </lightning:layoutItem>
 </lightning:layout>

 <div class="slds-modal__content slds-border_top">
  //calling child component
 </div>
</lightning:card>
```

[image]

UPDATE: I was able to remove the white space by adding margin -10px. But I dont wanna use the css, instead SLDS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already a footer element, which you've ignored in favor of trying to fake your own. That 10px space at the bottom is the empty footer where your footer content should go.

```
<lightning:card>
  //something here

 <aura:set attribute="footer">
   // bottom content here
 </aura:set>
</lightning:card>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the equivalent of this in LWC?

Comment: @Akash the lightning-modal in LWC provides a way to implement modals. There are corresponding header, body, and footer elements.